# What classes with rage abilities can a Skald multi-class into?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, multi-classing

Can a skald multi-class into something else that gives a rage ability. If so what? Supposedly it can based on the text

From the bottom of Rage Powers (Ex)

> If the skald has the ability to rage from another source, he can use his skald rage powers during that rage as well

I have heard that the skald cannot multiclass into a barbarian (or bard) since it is one of the parent classes of this hybrid class. Or rather a hybrid class cannot multi-class into one of its parent classes.

So then could it multi-class into Blood-Rager?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Skalds can multiclass into any other base class.

From the [PRD](https://legacy.aonprd.com/advancedclassguide/classes/index.html) or [PFSRD](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/):

> Each of the following classes draws upon two classes to form the basis of its theme. While a character can multiclass with these parent classes, doing so usually results in redundant abilities. Such abilities don't stack unless specified.

So a skald could have rage from multiclassing into barbarian (regular or unchained, but not both) or bloodrager.

#### Skalds might also multiclass into a prestige class that grants rage.

While there aren't many, some prestige classes *do* exist that grant rage or additional rage. Examples include the [Rage Prophet](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/apg/rage-prophet/) and [Furious Guardian](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/furious-guardian/).